# How to filter a query in flask-peewee by URL?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I'd like to run the following query by [flask-peewee](http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-api.html#filtering-records-and-querying),

**`merchant_name` LIKE  'seaside%'**

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `merchant_details` 
WHERE  `merchant_name` LIKE  'seaside%'
```

Here is the return JSON of the below URL and I need to filter the merhcnat_name 
http://www.XXXXX.com/api/merchant_details/

http://www.XXXXX.com/api/merchant_details/?merchant_name__like=seaside (This is not working)

```
{
  "meta": {
    "model": "merchant_details",
    "next": "",
    "page": 1,
    "previous": ""
  },
  "objects": [
    {
      "merchant_name": "Seaside Grill",
      "city": "Santa Monica ",
      "zipcode": "90401",
      "long": "-118.4884742",
      "phone": "3102399844",
      "state": "CA",
      "updated_on": "2013-11-07 01:14:42",
      "lat": "34.0189893",
      "street_1": "406 Broadway",
      "street_2": "1",
      "merchant_id": "1",
      "id": "2"
    },
{
  "merchant_name": "Jack n'  Jill's",
  "city": "Santa Monica",
  "zipcode": "90401",
  "long": "-118.4937635",
  "phone": "3109873733",
  "state": "CA",
  "updated_on": "2013-11-08 08:20:29",
  "lat": "34.0173215",
  "street_1": "510 Santa Monica Blvd",
  "street_2": "1",
  "merchant_id": "48",
  "id": "32"
}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode the url like this:

```
?merchant_name__like=seaside%25
```

You can get the encoded query string by `urllib.urlencode({'merchant_name__like': 'seaside%'})` , `?merchant_name__like=seaside` means `LIKE seaside` in sql.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How can we avoid the lower case and uppercase? Seaside%25 has a result, but seaside%25 doesn't have any result

Comment: you can use ilike instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[sqlalchemy-elasticquery](https://github.com/loverajoel/sqlalchemy-elasticquery)** that allow you make search like this:

```
?filters={ "merchant_nameseaside" : {"like" : "%seaside%"} }
```

and another custom filters.